# java script auto generate random string

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want the **random string result(output)** to display inside the **text box** so I can saved the value  into my database.

```js
(function() {
    function IDGenerator() {  
        this.length = 4;
        this.timestamp = +new Date;
   
        var _getRandomInt = function( min, max ) {
            return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
        }
   
        this.generate = function() {
            var ts = this.timestamp.toString();
            var parts = ts.split( "" ).reverse();
            var id = "TEST";
    
            for( var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i ) {
                var index = _getRandomInt( 0, parts.length - 1 );
                id += parts[index];  
            }
    
            return id;
        }
    }
  
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var btn = document.querySelector( "#generate" ),
            output = document.querySelector( "#output" );
   
        btn.addEventListener( "click", function() {
            var generator = new IDGenerator();
            output.innerHTML = generator.generate();
        }, false); 
    });
})();
```

```html
<p><button id="generate">Generate</button></p>
<p><code id="output"></code></p>
```

**NOTE**

Any idea on how to fix this? So when every time I click **generate button** the result will come out in a **text box** then save the value to my database.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the `.value` of an `<input>`? Anyway, you don't need an input to store things in a DB, you can use `fetch()` (ajax) to send data to your server.

Comment: _“any idea on how to fix this? ”_ - fix _what?_ You have not given us an actual problem description ... Please go read [ask].

Comment: wait what? you want to generate ID's on the client side? wow... long time since i've seen such a brilliant injection vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  function IDGenerator() {
  
   this.length = 4;
   this.timestamp = +new Date;
   
   var _getRandomInt = function( min, max ) {
   return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
   }
   
   this.generate = function() {
    var ts = this.timestamp.toString();
    var parts = ts.split( "" ).reverse();
    var id = "TEST";
    
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i ) {
    var index = _getRandomInt( 0, parts.length - 1 );
    id += parts[index];  
    }
    
    return id;
   }

   
  }
  
  
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector( "#generate" ),
   output = document.querySelector( "#output" );
   
  btn.addEventListener( "click", function() {
   var generator = new IDGenerator();
   $("#output").val(generator.generate());
  }, false); 
   
  });
  
  
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="generate">Generate</button></p>
 <input type="" id="output" name="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can replace code tag by input tag

```
<p><input id="output" type="text" value="" /></p>
```

and replace output.innerHTML to be

```
output.value= generator.generate();
```

Hope that's help